# rollup: Uncaught ReferenceError: async_hooks is not defined

Tags: javascript, browser, babeljs, rollupjs, lerna

I'm building a library with lerna + rollup and i want to create the .min file (which includes all dependencies within the library) starting from the main package, but after running it with the followings configs, i receive `async_hooks is not defined` within the browser.

These are my configs:

```
{
    input: 'src/index.js',
    output: {
      file: '../../dist/bundle.min.js',
      format: 'iife',
      sourceMap: 'inline'
    },
    plugins: [
      babel({
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        babelrc: false,
        babelHelpers: 'runtime',
        extensions: ['.mjs', '.js', '.json', '.node'],
        presets: [
          [
            '@babel/preset-env'
          ]
        ],
        plugins: [
          '@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from',
          '@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from',
          ['@babel/plugin-transform-runtime', {
            'helpers': true,
            'regenerator': true
          }]
        ]
      }),
      resolve({
        extensions: ['.mjs', '.js', '.json', '.node'],
      }),
      commonjs({
        include: /node_modules/,
        browser: true,
      }),
      json(),
      globals(),
      builtins(),
      terser()
    ]
  }
```